# method not running on ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have a function 'check' which I want to run that determines what to display in the page. I'm calling this function in ngOnInit. I dont know where else I could call it? Its not working. The logs are not being printed.

```
export class followersComponent implements OnInit {
  followers = [] 
  user
  following = [] 
  socket
  constructor(
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.socket = io(environment.server)
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.tokenService.GetPayload()
    this.GetUser()
    this.check(this.followers, this.following)
    this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => this.GetUser())
  }

  GetUser() {
    this.userService.getUserById(this.user._id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      if(res.followers.length) this.followers = res.followers
      if(res.following.length) this.following = res.following   
    })
  }
  unFollow(user) {
    this.userService.Unfollow(user).subscribe(() => this.socket.emit('refresh', {}), err => console.log(err))
}
Follow(user) {
  this.userService.follow(user).subscribe(() => this.socket.emit('refresh', {}), err => console.log(err))
}
  check(arr1, arr2) {
    arr1.forEach(el => {
      arr2.forEach(el2 => {
        if(el.follower._id === el2.userFollowed._id) {
          console.log(el)
        } else {
          console.log('no')
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Check maybe `followers` or `following` (or both) are empty when `check()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it doesn't print logs because at that moment `this.userService.getUserById()` call hasn't completed yet: this method is async, and when you call `this.GetUser()` and then `this.check(this.followers, this.following)`, the second method doesn't wait until the first is completed. You could try to call `check` from the `getUserById`'s callback:

```
this.userService.getUserById(this.user._id).subscribe((res: any) => {
  if(res.followers.length) this.followers = res.followers;
  if(res.following.length) this.following = res.following;
  this.check(this.followers, this.following); 
});
```